# twig replace замена % в строке

Tags: twig, replace

Как мне заменить `%` в строке

```
{{ title|replace({'%\%%': ключ}) }}
```

вот так не работает.

Comment: А зачем так экранировать? просто так должно работать - `{{ title|replace({'%': ключ}) }}`

Comment: Нет не работает.

Comment: https://twigfiddle.com/s8h83a

Comment: Спасибо действительно мая ошибка.